# Как сделать чтобы после запятой оставались только 2 знака без округления?

Tags: javascript, числа, округление

Вот выводится число 149.048 , а как сделать чтобы выводилось 149.04 без округления?

```
this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = Number((price * 1.202).toFixed(3));
this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = Number((price * 1.202).toFixed(2)); 
//(выводится 149.05)
```

---

```
  WithdrawOpenModal(i, id, name, price, priceWithMargin, image) {
     this.withdraw.item.i = i;
     this.withdraw.item.id = id;
     this.withdraw.item.name = name;
     this.withdraw.item.price = price;
     this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = Number((price * 1.202).toFixed(3));
     this.withdraw.modal = true;
```

вот код

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

Comment: напиши пожалуйста правильную строчку кода

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ оставить дробную часть числа без математического округления, это умножить его, округлить и поделить обратно

```js
const nStart = 123.7777777;
console.log('Начальное число', nStart);

const nMult = Math.floor(nStart * 100);
console.log('После умножения', nMult);

const nDiv = Math.floor(nStart * 100) / 100;

console.log('После деления', nDiv);
```

Если такие округления необходимо делать в нескольких местах кода, то можно создать свою универсальную функцию и использовать ее:

```js
function round(n, f) {
  const m = 10 ** f;
  return Math.floor(n * m) / m;
}

console.log(round(123.888, 0));
console.log(round(123.888, 1));
console.log(round(123.888, 2));
```

В вашем коде, это будет выглядеть так:

```
this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = Math.floor(price * 100) / 100;
```

или так

```
this.withdraw.item.priceWithMargin = round(price, 2);
```

Все [встроенные методы округления чисел](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#okruglenie) пытаются округлить число по своим правилам.

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var x of [-2, -1.89621, -1.8912, -1.7, 0, 1.7, 1.8912, 1.89621, 2]) {
  console.log(x, "=>", (Math.trunc(x * 100) / 100).toFixed(2))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для более точных вычислений с десятичными числами в JavaScript рекомендуется использовать библиотеки, такие как [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/)

Но если будут не очень большие значения, то можно попробовать использовать метод [Math.trunc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc):

```
let number = 149.048;
let formattedNumber = (Math.trunc(number * 100) / 100);
console.log(formattedNumber);
```

В выражении formattedNumber, исходное число (number * 100) умножается на 100, чтобы переместить два знака после запятой в целую часть. Это приводит к результату 14904.8. Функция Math.trunc() применяется к результату умножения и обрезает десятичную часть, оставляя только целое число. Теперь у нас есть 14904. Затем результат обрезанного числа делится на 100, чтобы вернуть два знака после запятой. Теперь мы получили числовое значение 149.04 где после запятой остались только две цифры.

Comment: нужно конкретно умножить на 1.202 (либо 20%) и убрать знаки после ,

Comment: Этот способ должен подойти: let formattedNumber = Math.trunc(number * 1.202);

Comment: выходит сумма 149, а должно выйти 149.04
тоесть я умножаю прайс айтема на 1.202, и после запятой должно быть 2 числа

Comment: В ответе код как раз выводит данную сумму 149.04